# Correct terminology for that circle/bubble with number of notifications in it?

Tags: buttons, terminology, notification, task-completion

Some applications will overlay some colored bubble/circle with a number to show how many unread messages/notifications or "things to do" are currently available.  For instance, it's on Skype to show how many conversations have unread messages.  It's also on my notifications area in Android for many things.  These are just a few examples of where they're found, but many more exist.

What is the correct terminology for this?

Comment: Notification flag?

Comment: @Styler: If we've answered your question, you can select the best solution so that if anyone comes across the same problem in the future, they know the course of action.

Comment: @dnbrv sorry forgot about this one ;)

Comment: @Styler: No worries.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apple refers to them as **Badges** as used by the [Apple Push Notification Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service) on iOS devices. More generally "Notification Badges" when discussed outside the context of notifications.

Anyone tinkering with iOS notifications is familiar with the term Badges to refer to these. Android apps sometimes use these to the same effect but I've heard them called varied things on that platform.

It's the most consistent name I've heard used but I believe Apple invented the term to maintain consistent terminology throughout iOS.

Comment: Yeah, it [looks like it's mainly used in iOS context](https://www.google.com/search?q="Notification+Badge") although there's some spillover into other applications as well.

Comment: I don't think there's a current standard but with all the users of iOS and applications of this concept outside of iOS (the Android uses of the idea seem to take directly from the idea) means that we might (hopefully) have a proper term for the idea.

Comment: Android uses are unofficial. I've gone through the entire [ICS style guide](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) and there's no mention of counters on icons à la iOS.

Comment: The _icon badges_ concept on Apple OS dates back to pre- OS X, and includes non-counter badges. This was back in the day where various utilities would overlay a mini-icon onto the document icon from another application to signify that that utility had done something - usually compression or backups. Later the concept included the visual design of a simple red disc containing a number representing a count, which was usually put there by the owning application and not a third party utility.

Comment: Not just document files either, badges got attached to folders too: "For example, you can specify that when a file is placed in one folder, it is always copied into another folder as well. If a folder has folder actions attached to it the folder's icon displays a small script icon badge." ... So, you might want to refer to the number in a bubble as a _notification badge_, not simply a badge.

Comment: @Erics The iOS terminology is clearly "badges" but as I said "notification badges" is more clear outside of iOS where the term has exclusive meaning

Comment: @dnbrv there's no OS support for them so they're certainly unofficial; several Homescreen apps like Go Launcher make use of them however.

Comment: I believe Android launch icons can't have a notification counter or notification badge

Comment: @NaoiseGolden: Android supports home screen widgets that can have such a badge.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're talking about `notification counter`.

Comment: Looks right, and you can call it about anything, notification bubble/icon/thingy. Counter sounds more standard. Are there references where this terminology is used?

Comment: Well, [2 million references on Google should do the trick](http://www.google.com/search?q=notification+counter+bubble).

Comment: Hey, look! This thread is #3

Comment: Actually, if you wrap your search as `notification counter`, which removes hits like `notification icon bubble counter`, it's only 26 500...

Comment: A large amount of the 2 million references do not say "notification counter" a specific phrase, most just contain both of these words.

Comment: >Well, 2 million references on Google should do the trick. 

dnbrv, Styler, ironically this is now #1 on that google search for me